# How to get random data from Json response in spring boot?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have a list of items from an API. I want only one element to be
returned as JSON response which can be the random or first element.

```
public Result makeGETApiRequest() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiKey);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
    ResponseEntity<Result> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Result.class);
    return response.getBody();
}
```

Result.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Result implements Serializable {
   List<Records> records;
   //getter and setter
}

class Records {
   Fields fields;
   //getter and setter
}

class Fields {
   @JsonProperty("Bank")
   String bank;
   @JsonProperty("Credit Card Count")
   int creditCardCount;
   @JsonProperty("Debit Card Count")
   int debitCardCount;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the function `makeGETApiRequest` return `Records` and in the `api` body handle that you get a random element

like this:

```
public Result makeGETApiRequest() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiKey);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
    ResponseEntity<Result> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Result.class);
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    return response.getBody().getRecords.get(rand.nextInt(response.getBody().getRecords().size() - 1));
}
```